# Is there a way of solving Uncaught Reference error and stating correct ORIGIN of a socket.io server on the client side when using vscode live server

Tags: javascript, liveserver, socket.io-client

I ran a socket.io client code using the liveserver extension on vscode and because i am using the version 2.5.0 i had to make use of [socket.io wildcard](https://github.com/hden/socketio-wildcard) I then ran the code and got 2 errors in the console[image: ..here is the picture]   from the first error there's apparently a problem with the second line of the code which is  `var BuiltInEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter`

```
'use strict'
var BuiltInEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

module.exports = function (CustomEmitter) {
  var Emitter = CustomEmitter || BuiltInEmitter
  var emit = Emitter.prototype.emit

  function onevent (packet) {
    var args = packet.data || []
    if (packet.id != null) {
      args.push(this.ack(packet.id))
    }
    emit.call(this, '*', packet)
    return emit.apply(this, args)
  }

  return function (socket, next) {
    if (socket.onevent !== onevent) {
      socket.onevent = onevent
    }
    return next ? next() : null
  }
}
```

the other error is from the client code I inputted `var patch = require('socketio-wildcard')(io.Manager); patch(socket);`.... it doesn't recognise the 'require'
..And as for the other question, the server I'm trying to make this connection to has a set ORIGIN header let's say its `https://xterm.com` how can I make the ORIGIN header on the client side `https://xterm.com` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:5500` ... thanks

Comment: Post the error text here as text, not just as image.

Comment: If you just read it you'd know i did... I made an edit just now

Comment: @deceze if you are unclear about anything please ask

Comment: The verbatim error message isn’t in your question, but well… Looks like you’re running code that is meant to be run on the backend in node in the browser instead!?

Comment: I'll use browserify to solve the require problem thanks... do you have an idea of the ORIGIN problem.. thanks in advance @deceze

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the wildcard issue, I had to install the library.. and as for the origin issue.. it can't be changed in the browser.. the browser automatically sets it.. if you want to change it you could make use of proxy servers